# CodeIgniter: load->view not working

Tags: view, load

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to load my other pages (about and details) from the controller as under:-

```
class Page extends CI_Controller
```

{

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Page_model');
    $data['result'] = $this->Page_model->getData();
    $data['page_title'] = "Page";
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('Page_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

function about()
{
    echo "about";
    $this->config->base_url();
    $this->load->view('About');
}

function details()
{
    $this->config->base_url();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('details', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

}

However, it seems the execution never enters about or details function. I have

`<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"> Home </a>  |
 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/about"> About </a> |
 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/details"> Details </a>`

on my header page. This page_view gets displayed but when I click the links, the respective functions do not get called and so those pages do not get displayed.

Please let me know where I am going wrong. I have been looking for hours now and not able to find a clue.

Thanks for your help,
Roshni

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/page/about"> About </a>
```